# How do I measure the distances between all pixels in a letter T

Tags: matlab, distance

I have an image like this:
[image: letter T]

and would need to measure the distance of all black pixels (which make up the letter T) from each other.
Can anyone recommend the best way?
I am particularly interested in the distance between pixels that make up the 'border' of the T, essentially this:

[image: letter T edge]

would you advise that I first turn the T into its own perimeter only (as in the second figure) and then map? Or is there a clever way to say "just map distances between pixels at the edge)?
many thanks

Comment: You can use `bwboundaries` to get the boundary pixels and then `pdist2` to get the distances between each pair of pixels, but I'm curious as to what you would do with this information. It seems a lot of computation to do on a very regular object.